# Best Squid Logfile Analysis Tool

Tags: linux, logging, statistics, monitoring, squid

I have recently been tasked with installing and configuring Squid Proxy server for filtering and monitoring our internal wireless network. I posted recently [requesting guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682099/best-squid-administrators-guidebook) in selecting a Guidebook for this project and you guys did a grade job there.  My next question is which Logfile Analysis tool does the stackoverflow community suggest?  The first and really only requirement is that it be open source/freeware.

The [Squid Main Page](http://www.squid-cache.org/Scripts/) has a good listing of available applications for this but very little data on the overall quality or popularity of each of these options.  What have you used in the past and why should I pick one of these over the other?

Answer (score 2):

calamaris is a good analyzer...